What's are some methodologies for managing modals/modal visibility in .NET Blazor?
I'm trying to figure out how to manage modals in my Blazor application. Currently, I have a Modal component that has a RenderFragment parameter and some callback functions that I'm using for most of the CRUD operations of different entities. The visibility of these modals is being handled by individual visibility Booleans in my on-page markup.
e.g.
@if(fooModalVisible){
   <Modal>{foo form content}</Modal>
}
@if(barModalVisible){
   <Modal>{bar form content}</Modal>
}

...

@code{
   private bool fooModalVisible { get; set; } = false;
   private bool barModalVisible { get; set; } = false;
}

How can I manage modal visibility for multiple modals in one component without using individual on-page booleans?

Not sure if it's well on topic for SO but have you considered taking some Blazor component library that is open source , like MudBlazor, and seeing if it contains anything you like the behavior of, and then looking in the code to see how they did it?

I also don't understand your question well, what you mean about without using individual on-page booleans, it's OK you could use custom razor component and use it, but it still need pass the value into that component.

You have here an example on how to do it without extra libraries: https://www.telerik.com/blogs/creating-a-reusable-javascript-free-blazor-modal

If you are using Bootstrap (or considering), look at
https://havit.blazor.eu/components/HxModal
It is pretty straightforward and easy to use. Advanced scenarios are supported with
https://havit.blazor.eu/components/HxDialogBase
Both free, open-source.
